# How do you bring the world in element and add html to it by jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, dom

I need to add Html + The Val in CheckBox ,

I added a Shortcode :

```
    <label class="HCheck">(this is val 1 )</label>
```

and the jQuery add to code to be a :

```
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 1 )<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"><span class="checkmark"></span></label>
```

but when I add some codes like :

```
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 1 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 2 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 3 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 4 )</label>
```

The Jquery Get All Vals and append to html like :

```
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 1 )(this is val 2 )(this is val 3 )(this is val 4 )<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"><span class="checkmark"></span></label>
```

My Jquery Code:

```
let HcheckVal = $('.HCheck').text();
$(".HCheck").html((HcheckVal + "<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'>" +
"<span class='checkmark'></span>"));
```

I want  to bring the same Val for each element ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop each label , one by one and override its content, using [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) by accessing the node using $(this) -> refer to current node :

See below snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  let HcheckVal = $('.HCheck');
  console.log(HcheckVal);
  
  $('.HCheck').each(function( index ) {
    
    $(this).html($(this).text() + "<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'>" + "<span class='checkmark'></span>");
    
  });
});
```

```css
.HCheck {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 1 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 2 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 3 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 4 )</label>
```

Comment: @MohamedAnwar you're welcome , I'm glad !

Answer (score 1):

Just use `append()` and you can ignore the text as it will stay in place

```js
$('.HCheck').append("<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'><span class='checkmark'></span>")
```

```css
.checkmark:after{content: '✔️'}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 1 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 2 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 3 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 4 )</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through `<label>` elements, so that you can *separately* set the html contents of each element:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('.HCheck').each(function (index) {

      console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
       
      let HcheckVal = $(this).text();
      $(this).html((HcheckVal + "<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'>" +
                    "<span class='checkmark'></span>"));       
   });           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="HCheck">(this is val 1 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 2 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 3 )</label>
<label class="HCheck">(this is val 4 )</label>
```

Comment: @MohamedAnwar Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.